# ActiveMQ Artemis broker connection

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a very simple Spring Boot 2.7.6 ActiveMQ Artemis app which listens for messages.

```java
package broker.consumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.start();
        return broker;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

Then I have another Spring Boot app which produces messages and sends them to the broker address.

```java
package broker.producer;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JmsProducer {

  @Value("${spring.artemis.broker-url}")
  private String brokerUrl;

  @Value("${spring.jms.template.default-destination}")
  private String defaultDestination;

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsProducer.class);

  @Bean
  public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
      log.info("BrokerUrl: {}", brokerUrl);
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

      return activeMQConnectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver() {
    return new JndiDestinationResolver();
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    template.setPubSubDomain(false); // false for a Queue, true for a Topic
    template.setDefaultDestinationName(defaultDestination);

    return template;
  }


  public void send(String message) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate();

    log.info("Sending message='{}'", message);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
    log.info("Sent message='{}'", message);
  }
}
```

With this simple `application.properties` for both apps.

```
spring.artemis.mode=EMBEDDED
spring.artemis.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=secret
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true

spring.jms.template.default-destination=my-queue-1
```

Then I start each of the apps and try calling `send` method and I keep getting this error from the producer app.

```
2024-01-15 15:50:28.462 ERROR 1012 --- [-netty-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client : AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:499) ~[artemis-core-client-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

Consumer app shows this error message:

```
2024-01-15 15:50:28.464  WARN 986 --- [0.1:57714@61616] o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport : Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57714 failed: Unknown data type: 77
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your consumer app is starting an embedded instance of ActiveMQ Classic. See this method:

```java
    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.start();
        return broker;
    }
```

Then your producer app is using the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS client implementation (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`) to connect and send a message. This client uses the "core" protocol which ActiveMQ Classic doesn't understand.

Your consumer app needs to start an embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis instead of ActiveMQ Classic. Spring itself should be doing this for you, but it may not be since you're starting your own already.

Comment: I need to add the BrokerService otherwise, I get this error:
`javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]] with root cause`

Comment: That indicates that your Spring application isn't starting the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis despite the configuration in your `application.properties`. I'm not a Spring expert but it looks like you may be missing the `@EnableJms` annotation on your consumer application.

Comment: I am following this doc: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/ which seems to work as one app, but I would like to connect to it using a different app using broker. thx

Comment: Following this doc: spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms broker does not seem to be configured and I can not find any documentation on how to do it using ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these suggestions seem to work. :(
I am able to connect just fine to ActiveMQ Artemis running in a Docker container.

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question about this specific issue.